# How to merge expression tree as Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> with navigation expression?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

How to merge expression tree as Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> with navigation expression Expresion<Func<TEntity,TProperty>>?
I need to create a generic code for query but the property for comparation can be dynamic depends by db.
My constant value depends from the user.

Example:
`builder.HasQueryFilter(x=>myConstantValue==navigationProperty)`

I tried different ways also to create 2 navigationProperty and to compare them with Expression.Equal

Comment: I do not understand question. Show what you have tried and I'll correct your code.

Comment: You may want to begin with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries#construct-expression-trees-and-queries-using-factory-methods).